# Data Table Grouped / Separated by Date

Tags: php, html

I have MySQL Table

| id | date | name | files |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-11 12:00:00 | OG Loc | God Rap |
| 2 | 2021-10-11 12:00:00 | Ryder | God Weedo |
| 3 | 2021-10-10 12:00:00 | Carl | God Child |
| 4 | 2021-10-10 12:00:00 | Johnson | God Cheat |
| 5 | 2021-10-10 12:00:00 | Big Smoke | God Crackzz |
| 6 | 2021-10-9 12:00:00 | Sweet | God Brother |

What i want to archive is, the data printed with **PHP** on table and separated / grouped by date:

| # | Ticket(id) | Date | Name | Files |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-11 |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-10-11 12:00:00 | OG Loc | God Rap |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-10-11 12:00:00 | Ryder | God Weedo |
| 2021-10-10 |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 3 | 2021-10-10 12:00:00 | Carl | God Child |
| 4 | 4 | 2021-10-10 12:00:00 | Johnson | God Cheat |
| 5 | 5 | 2021-10-10 12:00:00 | Big Smoke | God Crackzz |
| 2021-10-09 |  |  |  |  |
| 6 | 6 | 2021-10-9 12:00:00 | Sweet | God Brother |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body class="container mt-2">

<?php
$date=array();
$cars = array("2021-04-25","2021-04-26","2021-04-27","2021-04-25","2021-04-26","2021-04-25");

$date=array_unique($cars);
$no=1;
?>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
    <th>No</th>
    <th>Date</th>
</tr>
<?php
foreach($date as $d)
{
?>  
    <tr>
    <th colspan=2><?php echo $d; ?></th>
    </tr>
<?php
foreach($cars as $c)
{
    if($d == $c)
    {
?>
    <tr>
    <th><?php echo $no; ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $c; ?></th>
    </tr>
<?php
$no++;
}
}

}
?>

</body>
</html>
```